# asp.net adding class to current menuItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, menuitem, css

I am new the asp.net so i will appreciate a full code answer.

I have a web site in asp.net and c# i added  a menu to the site.master page it looks like this:

```
<asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" autopostback="true">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Pipes" Value="Pipes"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="View &amp; Query" Value="View &amp; Query"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="API" Value="API"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
```

I now need to add that when the user is on a specific page for example Pipes, then the right menuItem should have a different background color.

i can use a session  variable but i am not sure how to do that.

Can any one please write for me a full example for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: have navigationurl in MenuItem?

Comment: are you comfortable with jquery?

Comment: and whats the relevance of `AutoPostBack=true"` here?

Comment: @naveen,Im great with jquery, abd i dont know why AutoPostBack=true is here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need to track the page using session variables, as when you select a menu item, asp.net kindly tracks the item you've selected and generates its own CSS class for you (in most cases). To get a better visual download firebug for Firefox and look at the HTML output, you'll see they'll have CSS styles attached such as "asp-net.menu selectedItem" for example, you then create a .selectedItem{} CSS class, and then it will pick up the style automatically.

However If I recall it can be a bit fiddly styling Microsoft controls, as if you check the source code out of the output, its not exactly HTML friendly.

If you want to style the Menu item using the Microsoft approach, go here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx

However there is a library called CSSfriendly http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com/ that renders the control in pure HTML, which allows you to attach CSS classes much more easily. For example:

```
.CssAdapterMenu ul.AspNet-Menu /* Tier 1 */
{
    width: 961px !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.CssAdapterMenu ul.AspNet-Menu ul /* Tier 2 */
{
    left: 0;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    width: 145% !important;
    max-width: 160px !important;
}

.CssAdapterMenu ul.AspNet-Menu ul li:hover /* Tier 2 cell */
{
    background: #636363 url(../images/menu_bg_hover.png) no-repeat !important;
}

.CssAdapterMenu ul.AspNet-Menu ul .AspNet-Menu-Selected{
    background: transparent url(../images/menu_bg_hover.png) no-repeat !important;
}

.CssAdapterMenu li.AspNet-Menu-WithChildren li  .AspNet-Menu-ChildSelected {
    background: transparent url(../images/menu_bg_hover.png) no-repeat !important;
}
```

And so on and so forth. Theres good documentation out there for this, and its my preferred method for styling.

Amended your code with my explanations below.

```
<asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" autopostback="true">
<Items>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home" ></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="Pipes" Value="Pipes"></asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="View &amp; Query" Value="View &amp; Query</asp:MenuItem>
<asp:MenuItem Text="API" Value="API"></asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
<StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="menuItem" />
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="selectedItem" />
<StaticHoverStyle CssClass="hoverItem" />
</asp:Menu>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.normal{ 
background-color:#eaeaea; 
} 

.selected { 
background-color:#000000; 
}

.hover{
background-color:#FF0000; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i have firebug and i see that if i change a item to be select, (in edit menu items), then i gets the class selected. that fine. but now how does it dynamically add the right class to the right item? i am probably missing something, can you explain more clearly, how it is done.

Comment: When you create an asp page, you define a global stylesheet (style.css) in this stylesheet you have multiple classes .body{} .h1{} .p{} and so on. You need to create a class that corresponds with the class defined in the asp control. Usually you have to define the asp control like so: <asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" autopostback="true" CssClass="mainMenuCss"> then in your css file you add #mainMenuCss{ background-color:#eaeaea;} then for the child nodes mainMenuCss .selected-item{ background-color:#000000;}

Comment: or use the ASP control definitions:         

<StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="normal" />
<StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="selected" />
<StaticHoverStyle CssClass="hover" /> 
and add the css styles:
.normal{ background-color:#eaeaea; } .selected { background-color:#000000; }

Comment: Thanks for the accept. You might want to make a coffee and take an hour out and read about html + CSS and asp.net control styles. How they are rendered, and how styles are applied. A good knowledge of whats going on will help you to develop your site, quickly and efficiently :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
```

and

```
<StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
```

Besides usually you will need `NavigateUrl` attribute for your `MenuItem`. So the whole thing will look smth like:

```
<asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server" autopostback="true">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx" 
                 Value="Home" ></asp:MenuItem>
    ...
            </Items>
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" />
        </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: I am not getting something, how does the right item get the selected style??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any server-side methods. I normally resort to a client side method using jQuery. For that you should give your menu a `CssClass`. For example, `CssClass="mymenu"`

Inside your Master Page's head tag, do this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // not bothering about query strings and hash right now.
    var url = window.location.href.toString().split("/").pop();
    $(".mymenu a[href*='" + url + "']")
        .closest("li")
        .addClass("selected-item");
});
```

**Disclaimer**: I do not know a solution for this seemingly trivial requirement on Server Side. This is what I have been using. Oh! and this code works for ASP.NET 4.0. Prior to that the rendering was done using `table`. you might then want to change the closest to `.closest("td")`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I couldn't stylize each individual MenuItem.  Using this post...

[asp:MenuItem / CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390113/aspmenuitem-css/6390552#6390552)

...you could use code like the following:

```
<div>
    <asp:Menu ID="mainMenu" runat="server">
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="HOME" />
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Page1.aspx" Text="Page1" />
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
div.menu ul li a[href*="Default.aspx"]  { background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100); }
div.menu ul li a[href*="Page1.aspx"]    { background-color: rgb(150, 50, 100); }
```

Hope this helps somebody. :-)