# How to apply a class or id to a specific item in asp:Menu

Tags: asp.net, menu, styles, menuitem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [asp.net adding class to current menuItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826760/asp-net-adding-class-to-current-menuitem)

How can I 'mark' custom menu item with 'id' or 'class' property?I need it for applying custom style for it. For example look at stackoverflow menu - last item (ask question) has another style (margin-left).

**EDIT**

Here is my .css

```
div.menu ul
{ 
list-style: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: auto;
}

div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited
{
background-color: #660000;
border: 1px #4e667d solid;
display: block;
padding: 4px 20px;
margin-left  :0px;
margin-right  :20px;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
color:White;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover
{
background-color: #cc0000;
color: White;
text-decoration: none;
}

div.menu ul li a:active
{
background-color: #465c71;
color:White;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here code from .master

```
   <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu"EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal"></asp:Menu> 


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Home",null,null,"~/Default.aspx"));
        NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Home", null, null, "~/Default.aspx"));
        NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Home", null, null, "~/Default.aspx"));
        NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Home", null, null, "~/Default.aspx"));
        NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem("Home", null, null, "~/Default.aspx"));

    }
```

Comment: show us what you've done so far. show our code here.

Comment: is [this](http://forums.asp.net/post/3316885.aspx) what you want to achive?

Comment: near,but I want to mark item for css style.not for serverside actions.

Comment: @ivan Do you have this page somewhere live to see it - or if you see it with the browser tools you can find out how your must write the css so the style applied.

Comment: AFAIK It seems there is no way to add a class or id to a specific menuItem except the `selected` menu item. look at the [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.aspx) but still you have an option to use javascript to achieve your goal.

Comment: thanks @ArashMilani.I see it will be the best solution in this case.(I am always trying not to use javascript as possible but there is now other way to get simple solution)

Comment: I think this would help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366731.aspx

Comment: and he solved this issue - http://forums.asp.net/t/1465816.aspx/1